# Is There any Java agent to monitor the metrices of all JVM running processes in my POD?

Tags: kubernetes, stdout, splunk, kubernetes-pod, javaagents

I am looking for a java agent to monitor the metrics of all JVM running processes in my POD. I want to collect the metrics for each process like CPU, Memory and forward them to stdout or Splunk. How Can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do this, but I'll highlight 3 of them.

1. [Jolokia](https://jolokia.org) - Jolokia is remote JMX with JSON over HTTP.  You essentially enable this in your java arguments and it will spin up a server that allows you to request json.  You can also install hawtio online for a gui in kubernetes. If you go to Red Hat, the JBoss image has Jolokia installed by defaults.  That's how it does it's health checks.
2. [Prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter) - The Prometheus agent can also be installed.  You can also ask for metrics on an http/https port just like jolokia.
3. [OpenTelemetry](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-contrib/tree/main/jmx-metrics) - Opentelemetry is newer and I honestly haven't played around with it yet.

If you run [Red Hat JBoss images](https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/jboss-eap-7/eap74-openjdk11-runtime-openshift-rhel8/6054cfd24b028f6e10ce2e32) , both Prometheus and Jolokia extensions are added by default. Hope this helps, Jay